# Retrieve all user's HOMEPATH with windows command line

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to retrieve all users name's a HOMEPATH directory (the user may have manually change it to any path). My approach is to try to get them from the registry, using the following script:

```
@echo off
REM This is to change codification, so the commands can work with international characters paths 
chcp 1252 > NUL 

REM Check Windows Version (only needed to check if its Windows XP or not)
ver|findstr " 5." > NUL

set RESULT=%ERRORLEVEL%

if %RESULT% == 0 (set VERSION=XP
) else (
    set VERSION=7
)

REM Retrieve Public Desktop directory from environment variables
IF %VERSION%==XP (
    set PUBLICDESKTOPDIR=%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Desktop
    set USERSDIR=C:\Documents and Settings
) ELSE (
    set PUBLICDESKTOPDIR=%PUBLIC%\Desktop
    set USERSDIR=C:\Users
)

REM Copy configuration files to Cygwin home directory to all users in the system, so if setup is run under another user, it will have the files too
SET USERS="%USERNAME%"
SET USERSHOMEFOLDERS="%HOMEPATH%"
REM Command 'SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION' is necessary so variable substitution with ! works (so variable susbsitution works correctly in for loops)
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /D %%I in ("%USERSDIR%\"*) DO (  
    IF NOT "%%~nI" == "Public" (
        IF NOT "%%~nI" == "cyg_server" (
            IF NOT "%%~nI" == "Default User" (  REM Default User is in Windows XP
                IF NOT "%%~nI" == "All Users" (  REM All Users is in Windows XP
                    IF NOT "%%~nI" == "%USERNAME%" ( REM Skip current user as the data can be gathered from the user environment variables
                        SET USERS=!USERS! "%%~nI"
                        REM Load user data into a temporay folder into the registry
                        reg load HKU\Temp_data "!USERSDIR!\%%~nI\NTUSER.DAT"

                        REM Look for HOMEPATH variable in Volatile Environment folder
                        FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%A IN ('REG QUERY "HKU\Temp_data\Volatile Environment" /v "HOMEPATH"^|FIND/I "HOMEPATH"') DO SET HOMEDIRTMP=%%B
                        REM Check if HOMEDIRTMP is empty
                        IF "!HOMEDIRTMP!"=="" (
                            SET HOMEDIRTMP=!USERSDIR!\%%~nI
                        )
                        SET USERSHOMEFOLDERS=!USERSHOMEFOLDERS! "!HOMEDIRTMP!"
                        REM Unload temporary data
                        reg unload HKU\Temp_data
                    )
                )               
            )
        )
    )
)
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
```

The problem is that the "Volatile Environment" folder is only loaded for the current user. When the "NTUSER.DAT" is loaded in the registry, this folder does not exist and the HOMEPATH variable is not loaded anywhere else. Is there a way to get the HOMEPATH value for all users from the registry or from somewhere else?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51214309/edit) to show us the entire batch file you want help with instead of just telling us parts of it. _(We cannot help you if you only provide some of the information)_. Your actual question without it, i.e. the last sentence, is off topic, and more suited to [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) without it!

Comment: An account's roaming-profile directory and home directory are stored in the account database. You can query user account info via `NetUserGetInfo`, or on the command line via `net user <username>`. If the home directory is blank, `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%` will be the same as `%USERPROFILE%`.

Comment: @eryksun I have edited the question. Thank you for your comment. Your method works perfectly. If you can answer the question (it is edited), I will be able to mark it as correct. If not, I may post the answer myself corrected (with proper credits to you)

Comment: Feel free to write and accept your own answer, preferably with example code or pseudocode that demonstrates or explains the required steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @eryksun, which commented the possibility to use the `net` command, I changed the script so it uses this command instead of the registry (which is better, as it is better not to load and unload stuff in the registry).

The final code is the following:

```
@echo off
REM This is to change codification, so the commands can work with international characters paths 
chcp 1252 > NUL 

REM Check Windows Version (only needed to check if its Windows XP or not)
ver|findstr " 5." > NUL

set RESULT=%ERRORLEVEL%

if %RESULT% == 0 (
    set VERSION=XP
) else (
    set VERSION=7
)

REM Retrieve Public Desktop directory from environment variables
IF %VERSION%==XP (
    set PUBLICDESKTOPDIR=%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Desktop
    set USERSDIR=C:\Documents and Settings
) ELSE (
    set PUBLICDESKTOPDIR=%PUBLIC%\Desktop
    set USERSDIR=C:\Users
)

REM Copy configuration files to Cygwin home directory to all users in the system, so if setup is run under another user, it will have the files too
SET USERS=
SET USERSHOMEFOLDERS=
REM Command 'SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION' is necessary so variable substitution with ! works (so variable susbsitution works correctly in for loops)
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /D %%I in ("%USERSDIR%\"*) DO (  
    IF NOT "%%~nI" == "Public" ( 
        IF NOT "%%~nI" == "cyg_server" (
            IF NOT "%%~nI" == "Default User" (  REM Default User is in Windows XP
                IF NOT "%%~nI" == "All Users" (  REM All Users is in Windows XP
                    REM Append to USERS variable the new user
                    SET USERS=!USERS! "%%~nI"
                    FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%A IN ('net user "%%~nI"^|find "Home directory"') DO SET HOMEDIRTMP=%%B
                    REM If HOMEDIRTMP is empty, then set the default homepath directory
                    IF "!HOMEDIRTMP!"=="" (
                        SET HOMEDIRTMP=!USERSDIR!\%%~nI
                    )
                    REM Append to USERSHOMEFOLDERS vriable the new user's homepath
                    SET USERSHOMEFOLDERS=!USERSHOMEFOLDERS! "!HOMEDIRTMP!"
                )               
            )
        )
    )
)
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
```